# Прокси от NLog в Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, логирование, nlog

Как из `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` получить `NLog.ILogger`?
У меня в проекте используется `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` и настраивать `NLog` и все запускать через него не хочется. Но некоторые библиотеки требуют передачи в конструктор `NLog.ILogger` Есть ли какой-нибудь готовый прокси класс для этого? Что-то типа такого:

```cs
    public class NLogProxyLogger : NLog.ILogger
    {
        public NLogProxyLogger(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Готового не видел, но вообще вы уже написали практически весь wrapper.

Comment: `некоторые библиотеки требуют передачи в конструктор NLog.ILogger` - если вы унаследуетесь от него, ваш наследник туда тоже подойдет к этим библиотекам.

Comment: Ну да, просто там методов много, лень писать, дмал может уже есть готовое, ладно, буду писать своё